# How to Change the RadioButton Pressed State in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, radio-button

I am using two RadioButtons for a selection option in my application, and instead of having the default accent color be shown when a RadioButton is pressed, I would like to have my own color `#FF1BA1E2'. This is for custom theming purposes. How might I change this state to account for this? So far what I have is as follows, which implmements the RadioButtons but not the custom color feature.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
<RadioButton x:Name="ascendingSortRadioButton" Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPage_PictureSortOrder_Ascending, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                     GroupName="pictureSort" Checked="radioButton_Check">
                        <RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                    </RadioButton>

                    <RadioButton x:Name="descendingSortRadioButton" Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPage_PictureSortOrder_Descending, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                     GroupName="pictureSort" Checked="radioButton_Check">
                        <RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                    </RadioButton>
```

Do I need a custom style? And If so, how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit the press state of your RadioButton you will need to edit his style. To edit the Style of a control, open the outline windows > find your control in the tree> click right > Edit Template> Edit a copy. It will generate a style such as the following :

```
        <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="CheckBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,0,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

What you want to modify are the color defined in the Pressed State of the visual state of RadioButtonStyle1

Comment: Is it possible to just keep the `RadioButtonStyle1` and remove everything else? Or is `RadioButtonStyle1` dependent upon the other styles?

Comment: Edited my response to remove the other style (and remove basedOn). This will work because the properties will be inherited from the RadioButton based style anyway